# Saints Who Correlated the Prosperity of an Age to Its Devotion to the Holy Eucharist

Tags: catholicism, communion, saint, devotion, real-presence

Consider the following quote of St. Peter Julian Eymard:

> An age prospers or dwindles in proportion to its devotion to the Holy Eucharist. This is the measure of its spiritual life and its faith, of its charity and its virtue.

QUESTION: Are there other Catholic Saints who have expressed similar thoughts regarding the connection between the rise and fall of a people and the devotion (or respect) they pay to the Holy Eucharist? If so, who are they and what did they say regarding the aforesaid connection?

All Saints, I am quite sure, have had a devotion to the Holy Eucharist; I am interested only in those who have verbalized a connection similar to the one given above by St. Peter Julian Eymard.

Comment: In Chapter 8 (p. 195) of Trochu's biography of St. John Vianney published in 2007 by TAN, the author declares: ``he [the Saint] was far-sighted enough to realize that devotion to the Eucharist is, and always will be, the most powerful means towards the regeneration of a people. ''